# php regexp question

Tags: php, regex

How to catch and filer the below filename

**Input:**

```
../images/imgac00000001.jpg
../images/imgbc00000002.jpg
../images/img1111.jpg
```

**Outout:**

```
imgac00000001
imgbc00000002
```

I have tried in PHP using preg_replace, which I dont howto use correctly.

```
preg_replace('/(img)[a-z]{0,2}[0-9]*/i', '$1', $img_path);
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't want `img1111` in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `preg_match_all`, not `preg_replace`

```
$input = <<<EOF
../images/imgac00000001.jpg
../images/imgbc00000002.jpg
../images/img1111.jpg
EOF;

//imgac00000001
//imgbc00000002


preg_match_all('/img[a-z]{0,2}[0-9]*/i', $input, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => imgac00000001
            [1] => imgbc00000002
            [2] => img1111
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to fetch file names :

```
$file_info = pathinfo('../images/imgac00000001.jpg');
print $file_info['filename'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the base path is the same, why not use str_replace?

```
mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )

$image = "../images/imgac00000001.jpg";
$name = str_replace(array('../images/','.jpg','.png'),'',$image);
```

You could use `str_ireplace()` for a case insensitive situation.

[Manual on str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try `preg_replace('/((img)[a-z]{0,2}[0-9]*)/i', '$1', $img_path);` put extra parenthesis around the whole expression.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex, you could do something this:

```
$str = '../images/imgac00000001.jpg';
$str = array_shift(explode('.', end(explode('/', $str))));
```

But here's your regex:

```
$str = '../images/imgac00000001.jpg';
preg_match('/\/([^\/\.]+)\./', $str, $matches);
```